# How to read a file using jquery and get content of head and body?

Tags: jquery, readfile

I'm trying to read a html file and get the content of head and  body tags using jquery. But no luck for me. This is the code i'm using. It worked for me to find the content of a id or a class. But not with head and body tags?  Hope you guys can help me out soon. Thanks.

```
$.get(file, function(response) { alert(response);
        alert($(response).filter('body').html());
                    //is null
                  alert($(response).filter('head').html());
                    //is null
     });
```

Comment: Alerting things can get EXTREMELY annoying. You should use `console.log()` (assuming you have firefox or Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

I was using a hand-made filtering function. Basically it converts heads, htmls and meta tags into divs and paragraphs so they don't get lost along the way. This was my function, you might want to adapt it for something else.

```
function filterInput(sx){

    var t = new Date().getTime();
    var strip_only = function (input,only){only=(((only||"")+"").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g)||[]).join('');var tags=/<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,commentsAndPhpTags=/<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags,'').replace(tags,function($0,$1){return only.indexOf('<'+$1.toLowerCase()+'>')===-1?$0:'';});};

    sx = sx.replace(new RegExp('<html.*?>','gmi'),'').replace(new RegExp('</html>','gmi'),'');
    /* strip out head & body tags */
    sx = sx.replace(new RegExp('<head.*?>','gmi'),'<div id="u_'+t+'_head">')
        .replace(new RegExp('</head>','gmi'),'</div>')
        .replace(new RegExp('<body.*?>','gmi'),'')
        .replace(new RegExp('</body>','gmi'),'');
    /* replace title tag */
    sx = sx.replace(new RegExp('<title.*?>','gmi'),'<p id="u_'+t+'_title">')
        .replace(new RegExp('</title>','gmi'),'</p>');
    /* replace meta tags */
    sx = sx.replace(new RegExp('<meta','gmi'),'<p');
    sx = strip_only(sx,'<img><link><style>');

    /* wrap */
    sx = $("<div>"+sx+'</div>');

    return sx;
}
```

Comment: ok, if i use this how can i alter this to find content of head or body?

Comment: Delete `var t = new Date().getTime()` and pass it as function parameter (function filterInput(sx **,t**)). Then use `var t = new Date().getTime(); var html = filterInput(response.responseText,t); var head = $('div#u_'+t+'_head',html); var title = $('p#u_'+t+'_title'); //...`. For body delete body/body tag and make it look like head, just read the code, it's easy and it makes sense.