# Loading text from one html to two columns in another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one xhtml file with text in it and another html file with a table and two columns in it. What i want to do is, i need to load the text from the xhtml file to the two columns of html file . While loading the second column should have the continuation of data from the first column . How can this be done using javascript.?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765064/how-to-read-a-file-using-jquery-and-get-content-of-head-and-body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `get()` function to retrieve the content from the table.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

This example fetches the requested HTML snippet and inserts it on the page.

Comment: but i need to load the text into two columns of a table in that html file... with the 2nd column having a continuation of data from the 1st column. Now am able to display the content in one column. But the the 2nd column should have continued data from the 1st column.

Comment: then split the get request in half